# Titanium Music player progress event listener status not firing

Tags: javascript, ios, audio, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have a music player that is not updating the progress.

Pausing and playing the music works without problem for example:

```
if (music.isPlaying()) {
    var btnsrc = '../images/btn_pause.png'
} else {
    var brnsrc = '../images/btn_play.png';
}

var playButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title: '',
    backgroundImage: '../images/btn_pause.png',
    width:34,
    height:34,
    top:10,
    left:10
});

playButton.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    if (!music.isPaused()) {
        music.pause();
    } else {
        music.play();
    } 
});
```

But when I add the event listener, it never fires:

```
if (!music.isPlaying()) {   
    Ti.API.info('novid=' + robj.curel);     
    var nove = {index: robj.curel+2, rowData: {}};
    nove.rowData.tourid = robj.tour;
    dispLocDetails(nove);
    music = Ti.Media.createSound({url:"../sounds/" + playlist[0].id + ".mp3"});     
    music.play();   
    music.complete = function(){        
        playlist.splice(0,1)        
        if (playlist.length!=0){
            music = Ti.Media.createSound({url:"../sounds/" + playlist[0].id + ".mp3"});                 
            music.play();                                                   
        }   
    };

    music.addEventListener('progress',function(e) {
        Ti.API.info('Time Played: ' + Math.round(e.progress) + ' milliseconds');    
    }); 
}
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

You are adding event listener to [Ti.Media.Sound](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Media.Sound) object looking for `progress` event. This object is emitting only `change`, `complete`, `error`, `interrupted`, `resume` events. The object which you are looking for is [Ti.Media.AudioPlayer](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Media.AudioPlayer-event-progress).

Also with AudioPlayer you don't need to recreate whole object to skip to next track. Just use `setUrl()` method:

```
music.setUrl("../sounds/" + playlist[0].id + ".mp3");
```

Comment: Thank you Titanium guru. This would explain the many hickups i've been having :)

Comment: Wait, problem! now it crashes!   var music = Ti.Media.createAudioPlayer({ 
   url:"../sounds/1.mp3",
      allowBackground: true
  });
  music.start();

Comment: Turns out audioplayer does not support local files. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: Have you tried passing absolute path to your local file using `file://` prefix?

Comment: I get unable to configure network read stream on this: url:"file://Resources/sounds/1.mp3",